Solving $x - 6 < 3\lfloor4 - 2x\rfloor\leq 7+6x$
How to solve
$$x - 6 < 3\lfloor4 - 2x\rfloor\leq 7+6x$$
The only I know is that if I have an integer $m$ and it satisfies
$$\lfloor x \rfloor = m$$,
Then I'd have
$$m\leq x < m+1$$
Now, I believe since I have to isolate the $x$, I have to break them up into $2$ problems. I.e.
$$x - 6 < 3 \lfloor 4 - 2x \rfloor$$, and
$$3 \lfloor 4 - 2x \rfloor \leq 7 + 6x$$
It's easy to determine the infimum and the supremum were the upper and the lower bounds integers or at least numbers that are known, though it can have fractional parts. However, they have an $x$ that confuses me. It somehow leads me to think that I have to find:
$$\left\lceil \dfrac{x-6}{3} \right\rceil \leq 4 - 2x$$
instead, for instance, (for the first problem).
If you ask me why, I think I have to think of a number, in terms of $$\dfrac{x-6}{3}$$
that will be rounded up to have the "$\leq$" sign.
What's so great? I just made the original question more complicated. And it's difficult to determine the appropriate infimum and supremum if the "$x$" is unkown. Please help and Thank you in advance.
Edit: (Second attempt)
Even though I use the original definition, I'm still struggling to get the gist. I'm not able to find the value of "$x$"


My standard approach is to set $~x = P + r,~$ where $~P \in \Bbb{Z},~$ and $~0 \leq r < 1.$  This approach should defeat this math problem.

@user2661923 Still don't know how to start. Isn't it the same as saying if I have $\lfloor x \rfloor = P$, then $P\leq x \lt P+1$? I have tried to do anything with it still haven't any clue to find $x$.


I don't think I explained it very well in my first attempt.  I'm going to leave it up, but I'm going to include a second explanation after word to make things more clear

There's nothing magical about finding the greatest integer less than or equal to.  We can just as easily find any range of $d$ where $md \le x < (m+1)d$ or where $(m-1)d < x \le md$.
So one trick is to note that as we are dealing with $4-2x$ we can  try to affix $x$ between half integers.
That is to say: that if $[4-2x]=  m\in \mathbb Z$ then $m \le 4-2x < m+1$ so $\frac {3-m}2 < x \le \frac{4-m}2$.
In other words we can find $k\in \mathbb Z$ were $\frac k2 -\frac 12 < x \le \frac k2$.  There's nothing magical about that.  Obviously we can hone $x$ into and interval $\frac 12$ long.  The only question is why?
Well, let's just do it.  Suppose $\frac k2 - \frac 12 < x \le \frac k2$ and let say that $x = \frac k2 - r$ were $0\le r < \frac 12$.
The so get $[4-2x]$ we just note that if $x =\frac k2 -r; 0\le r < \frac 12$ then $4-2x = 4-k +2r; 0\le 2r < 1$.  So....
$4-k \le 4-k+2r = 4-2x < (4-k) + 1$.  And so...
$[4-2x]=4-k$.
Now our expression
$x - 6 < 3\lfloor4 - 2x\rfloor\leq 7+6x$ becomes...
$\frac k2-r -6 < 3(4-k) \le 7+6(\frac k2 -r)$
Let's deal with this in two parts
First $\frac k2 -6 -r < 12 -3k$
$k-12-2r < 24-6k$
$7k < 36 + 2r$
$k < \frac {36}7+\frac {2r}7 < \frac {36}7 + \frac 17=\frac {37}7$ and as $k$ is an integer $k \le 5$.
We also have $12-3k \le 7+3k -6r$ so $
$5+6r \le 6k$
$\frac 56 +r \le k$.
Again as $k$ is an integer we have $k\ge 1$.  So $1\le k \le 5$.
If $k=1$ we have $\frac 56    +r \le 1$ so $0\le r \le \frac 16$.  That means $x=\frac 12 - r$ and $0\le r \le \frac 16$ so $\frac 13 \le x \le \frac 12$.
If $2 \le k \le 5$ we always have $\frac 56+r< \frac 56+\frac 12 < k-\frac 12$ so we don't have to worry about the value of $r$.
So $x$ can be any value of $\frac k2 -r$ where $k=2,3,4,5$ and $0\le r < \frac 12$ or $k=1$ and $0\le r \le \frac 16$.
That means $x$ can be anything where $\frac 13 \le x \le \frac 52$.

Second explanation

It's pretty obvious that if we have a real number $x$ there has to be a unique integer $n$ where $n \le x$ but the next integer, $n+1$ is larger than $x$.
But there's nothing magical that we have to look for integers.  It's maybe not as obvious but clearly there is some unique even integer $2k$ where $2k\le x$ and the next even integer, $2k+ 2$ is larger so $2k \le x < 2k+2$.
Or some unique multiple of $13$ where $13m \le x < 13(m+1)$.  And it doesn't have to an integer it could be a fraction.  There is some unique multiple of $\frac 16$ where $\frac j6 \le x < \frac {j+1}6$.
(This is called the archimedean principal.  For any real number $x$ and any positive quantity $d$.  We can keep adding or subtracting $d$ to find some unique interval where $m\times d \le x$ but $(m+1)d > x$.)
And it doesn't need to be the greatest integer less that or equal to $x$.  There is also a unique integer that smallest integer that is more or equal.  That is, there is a unique $n'$ were $n'\ge x > n'-1$ or or unique multiple of $\frac 16$ where $\frac j6 \ge x > \frac {j-1}6$.
So... heres a useful trick.  When we have something like $[mx + b]$ is the unique integer where $N \le mx+ b < N+1$.  This pins $mx+b$ between integers.  But we don't care about pinning $mx+b$; we care about pinning $x$.  $N\le mx + b < N+1 \iff \frac {(N-b)}m \le m < \frac{(N-b)+1}m$.  So we don't care about pinning $x$ down to an integer.  We care about pinning $x$ down to a nearest $\frac 1m$ equal or less than $x$.
Furthermore if we have something $[b-mx]$ so $N\le b-mx < N+1$ but $N\le b-mx < N+1 \iff \frac {N-b}m \le -x < \frac {(N-b)+1}m \iff \frac {(b-N)-1}m < x \le \frac {(b-N)}m$.  So we aren't trying pin $x$ to the nearest $\frac 1m$ equal or less than $x$; we are trying to pin $x$ to the nearest $\frac 1m$ equal or greater than $x$.
... Okay....
So we are dealing with $[4-2x]$.  So let pin $x$ to the nearest $\frac 12$ that is equal or greater than it.  That is to say suppose $\frac {k-1}2 < x \le \frac k2$.
Then $[4-2x] = 4-k$.  Why?  $\frac {k-1}2 < x \le \frac k2\implies k-1 < 2x \le k\implies -k\le -2x < -k+1\implies 4-k \le 4-2x < (4-k) + 1\implies $[4-2x] = 4-k$.
So $x - 6 < 3\lfloor4 - 2x\rfloor\leq 7+6x$
$x-6 < 3(4-k) \leq 7+6x$.
...
Now here is my second common trick.
It's useful to write out $x$ in terms of $k$.  But how do we do that exactly.  We know that $\frac {k-1}2 < x \le \frac k2$ but what is $x$ exactly?
Well, we've pinned $x$ down to the nearest $\frac 12$ equal or more than $x$.  That means there is some "remainder" $r$ where $x = \frac k2 -r$ where $0\le r < \frac 12$.  In other words $\frac {k-1}2=\frac k2-\frac 12 < \frac k2-r = x \le \frac k2-0 =\frac k2$.
Putting $x = \frac k2-r$ into our inequality we get:
$x - 6 < 3\lfloor4 - 2x\rfloor\leq 7+6x$
$\frac k2 - r -6 < 3(4-k) \le 7 + 6(\frac k2 -r)$.
Viewing this in two pieces we get
$\frac k2 -6-r <12 -3k$
$k-12 -2r < 24 -6k$
$7k < 36 + 2r$
$k < \frac {36 + 2r}7$
Now as $0\le r < \frac 12$ we have $36 \le 36 + 24 < 37$.  So $k$ is an integer and $k < \frac {36+2r}7 < \frac {37}7 =5\frac 27$ we know that $k \le 5$.  And that means that $x = \frac k2 - r\le \frac 52 -r \le \frac 52$.
The second half is
$3(4-k) \le 7+6(\frac k2 -r)$
$12 -3k \le 7+3k-6r$
$5 +6r \le 6k$
$\frac 56 + r \le k$
As $k$ is an integer this means $k \ge 1$.  So $1 \le k \le 5$.
ANd $x = \frac k2 - r; 0\le r < \frac 12$ can be as high as $k=5; r=0$ and $x = \frac 52 -0 =\frac 52$.
Or it can be as low as $k=1$ and $x=\frac 12-r$.  But how low can $r$ be.  If $k = 1$ then we have $\frac 56 +r \le 1$ or $r \le \frac 16$ so $x=\frac 12-r \ge \frac 12 -\frac 16 = \frac 13$.
So $\frac 13 \le x \le \frac 52$.

+1 thanks, but when I substitute $x=4$ why does it not work?

Because I made a stupid transcription error.  It is $k$ that can be $k =1,2,3,4$ or $5$, not $x$.  $x = \frac k2 -r$ so $x$ can be as low as $\frac 12 -\frac 16$ or as high as $\frac 52 - 0$  A really brain fart on my part.  The actual answer is $x \in[3, \frac 52]$.

You're awesome! Umm. One more or two pls. I don't understand as to why you added the extra $d$ in $md\leq x \lt (m+1)d$ when the original definition is $m\leq x \lt x+1$? The second one is about the appearance of $k$. How did you change $\frac{3-m}{2}$ into $\frac k2 - \frac 12$

Read my second explanation.  You may want to google Archemedean property.


How to solve
$$x - 6 < 3\lfloor4 - 2x\rfloor\leq 7+6x$$

The point of this response is to attempt to provide a universal method of attacking all such problems.  Start with the following premise:
$$x = P + r ~: ~P \in \Bbb{Z}, ~0 \leq r < 1.$$
Before attacking the problem, you have to diagnose how the choices for $~P~$ and $~r~$ will affect the expression $~\displaystyle \left\lfloor 4 - 2x\right\rfloor.$
To help with the diagnosis, consider the following three cases :

Case 1: $~x = P + r ~: ~r = 0.$ 
Then $~2x = 2P \implies \lfloor 4 - 2x\rfloor  = \lfloor 4 - 2P\rfloor = 4 - 2P.$

Case 2: $~x = P + r ~: ~0 < r \leq 1/2.$ 
Then $0 < 2r \leq 1.$ 
Then $~2x = 2P + 2r \implies 2P < 2x \leq 2P + 1.$ 
Therefore, $~(4 - 2P - 1) \leq 4 - 2x < (4 - 2P).$ 
Therefore, $~\lfloor 4 - 2x\rfloor = (4 - 2P - 1) = (3 - 2P).$

Case 3: $~x = P + r ~: ~1/2 < r < 1.$ 
Then $~1 < 2r < 2.$ 
Then $~2x = 2P + 2r \implies 2P + 1 < 2x < 2P + 2.$ 
Therefore, $~(4 - 2P - 2) < 4 - 2x < (4 - 2P - 1).$ 
Therefore, $~\lfloor 4 - 2x\rfloor = (4 - 2P - 2) = (2 - 2P).$


So, the strategy to conquer the problem is now clear.  You simply explore each of the above three (mutually exclusive) cases separately, and see where each one leads.
However, this begs the question: how did I know that the relevant cases would be $~r = 0,~$ or $~0 < r \leq 1/2,~$ or $~1/2 < r < 1 ~?$
There is no hard and fast rule here.  That is, suppose that you encountered a problem that contained an expression like $~\displaystyle \left\lfloor 4 - \frac{2x}{3} \right\rfloor ~$ or an expression like $~\displaystyle \left\lfloor 4 - \frac{2x}{3} + \frac{5x}{7} \right\rfloor ~?$
So, in general, starting with the premise that $~x = P + r,~$ I see no alternative to experimentation.  That is, take out scratch paper, and manually experiment with various values of $~P~$ and $~r~$ and attempt to diagnose how they affect the evaluation of
$$\left\lfloor ~\text{some expression in} ~x ~\right\rfloor.$$
Anyway, back to the specific question that was posted...

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~r = 0}$
From the preceding analysis,
$$\lfloor 4 - 2x\rfloor  = 4 - 2P.$$
Therefore, since $~x = P,~$ and $~P~$ is an integer:
$$P - 6 < 3(4 - 2P) \leq 7 + 6P.$$
So,
$$P - 6 < 12 - 6P \iff 7P < 18 \iff P \leq 2.$$
$$12 - 6P \leq 7 + 6P \iff 5 \leq 12P \iff 1 \leq P.$$
So, in Case 1, you must have
$$P \in \{ ~1, ~2 ~\}, ~r = 0.$$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~0 < r \leq 1/2}$
From the preceding analysis,
$$\lfloor 4 - 2x\rfloor  = 3 - 2P.$$
$$(P + r) - 6 < 3(3 - 2P) \leq 7 + 6(P + r).$$
So,
$$P + r < 15 - 6P \iff 7P + r < 15.$$
Within Case 2, where $~0 < r \leq 1/2,~$ the above inequality will be satisfied if and only if $~P \leq 2.$
Then,
$$9 - 6P \leq 7 + 6P + 6r \iff 2 \leq 12P + 6r.$$
Note that in Case 2, to satisfy the above inequality, besides having $~P \geq 1,~$ you can also have
$$P = 0, \frac{1}{3} \leq r \leq \frac{1}{2}.$$
So, in Case 2, you must have
$$P \in \{ ~1, ~2 ~\}, ~0 < r \leq \frac{1}{2}$$
or
$$P = 0, ~\frac{1}{3} \leq r \leq \frac{1}{2}.$$

$\underline{\text{Case 3:} ~1/2 < r < 1}$
From the preceding analysis,
$$\lfloor 4 - 2x\rfloor  = 2 - 2P.$$
$$(P + r) - 6 < 3(2 - 2P) \leq 7 + 6(P + r).$$
So,
$$P + r < 12 - 6P \iff 7P + r < 12.$$
Within Case 3, where $~1/2 < r < 1,~$ the above inequality will be satisfied if and only if $~P \leq 1.$
Then,
$$6 - 6P \leq 7 + 6P + 6r \iff -1 \leq 12P + 6r.$$
Within Case 3, where $~1/2 < r < 1,~$ the above inequality will be satisfied if and only if $~P \geq 0.$
So, in Case 3, you must have
$$P \in \{ ~0, ~1 ~\}, ~\frac{1}{2} < r < 1.$$

$\underline{\text{Final Summary}}$
So, the complete list of all satisfying values of $~x~$ is 
$x = P + r, ~$ where one of the following conditions is satisfied:

$r = 0, ~P \in \{ ~1,  ~2 ~\}.$

$0 < r \leq \dfrac{1}{2}, ~P \in \{ ~1,  ~2 ~\}.$

$\dfrac{1}{3} \leq r \leq \dfrac{1}{2}, ~P = 0.$

$\dfrac{1}{2} < r < 1, ~P \in \{ ~0,  ~1 ~\}.$



I'm familiar with this kind of solution. Now I'm thinking of solving an absolute value inequality. I.e. we have to find critical points as those points tell as which point would make the term inside the absolute sign will alter from negative to positive... Can we do the same in this floor sign? But instead of finding the critical points, we have to find points that tell us which point alters from an integer to non-integer? Since there are only 2 possibilities about the value inside the floor sign. I.e. integer and non integer.

+1 By the way, thank you very much for sharing your thoughts

@user516076 It's not that simple.  As I indicated, I don't think that it is a good idea to try and develop hard and fast rules, because you can't anticipate what the expression inside the floor function will be.  For example, I would not advise trying to find a rule that covers $$\left\lfloor 4 - \frac{2x}{3} + \frac{5x}{7} \right\rfloor.$$  Instead, I think that a far better approach is to take each such problem, one at a time.  That is, for each such problem, simply take out scratch paper and experiment.
